# Facebook messenger calls, show only short name

Tags: ios, contacts, facebook

When someone calls me on my FB messenger I can only see their short name. I noticed this change after I updated my iPhone to iOS14. Does anyone know how can I change it back? I have multiple people with the same short name and it is very difficult for me to understand who is who.

I'm positive that I configured contacts properly like [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202590) yet messenger refuses to show full names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [setting the Messages display name](https://osxdaily.com/2013/09/21/set-messages-to-display-full-names-in-ios-7/) and see if Facebook Messenger respects it; however, I'm not sure if this will help.

> 1. Open Settings and go to “Mail, Contacts, Calendars” then scroll down to the ‘Contacts’ section and go back to “Short Name”, then
>    choose one of the following options:
>
>    - First Name & Last Initial – good middle ground choice
>    - First Initial & Last Name Only
>    - First Name Only – the annoying default
>    - Last Name Only – OK if you’re on a football team
>    - Optionally, set “Prefer Nicknames” to your preference
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Go back to Messages and view a thread to see the change.
>
> [image]

Comment: No sorry this didn't work for me :( Maybe I should add a screenshot to clarify what I see.